# Adding text for specified paragraphs in Word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a Word document, and an Excel file, in which there are some of the Word's headings listed with number and text.

After adding some extra information in the Excel (in other cells next to the headings text) I'll have to put these infos back to my Word doc. After each and before the next referred heading,there is somewhere a token. This token should be replaced with the additional text from the Excel file.

I can't find out, how to find the headings by text from the Excel.

Could somebody help, how to start?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Content.Find object in Word: #1

Then loop through your Excel range,  to find and replace tokens in the Word document #2

```
    ' #1 Open the Word document
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True 
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("Your Word document path")

    ' #2 Loop your Excel range to find and replace tokens in the Word
    Set WordRange = WordDoc.Content
  
    'Before get into below code, assign Heading, Info value from your Excel range
    With WordRange.Find
        .Text = "Token for " & Heading 
        .Replacement.Text = Info 
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
```